# PunRPC not getting called

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

I received a warning saying that Received RPC "Winner" for viewID 0 but this PhotonView does not exist! Was remote PV. Remote called. By: 1 Maybe GO was destroyed but RPC not cleaned up.

It also does not call the RPC "Winner". My Code:

```
public Text Score_;
public PhotonView photon;
public GameObject GUn;
public string yooh;
public GameObject WIn;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    yooh = "Score: " + PhotonNetwork.player.GetScore();
    Score_.text = yooh;
    if (PhotonNetwork.player.GetScore() == 40)
    {
        photon.RPC("Winner", PhotonTargets.All);
    }
}

public void SetScore()
{
    PhotonNetwork.player.AddScore(10);
    Debug.Log("done");
}

[PunRPC]
public void Winner()
{
    WIn.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: You should probably not call an RPC **every frame** to begin with ...

Answer (score 0):

> Received RPC "Winner" for viewID 0 but this PhotonView does not exist!
> Was remote PV. Remote called. By: 1 Maybe GO was destroyed but RPC not
> cleaned up

This warning means that the RPC event was received but PUN did not find the corresponding PhotonView (ViewID 0) locally on the client in order to call "Winner" RPC method.
We suspect that either the networked object got removed somehow (scene change? Destroy method?) or, less likely, the networked room object with ViewID 0 was not instantiated locally yet.
So you need to figure out first why the networked room object with ViewID 0 is missing on the receiving client.

And as @derHugo mentioned in the comment, do not call RPCs in `Update`.